# How to extract sessionid from cookie data in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, request, extract, response, sessionid

The response is:
Set-Cookie: sessionid=YUuyisdjif7njdibvck89987hgfdghjuytrdtyRB==;

I want to extract this sessionid to use it in further response.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)'s built-in capability of saving cookies into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

1. Add the [next line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the change
3. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your test plan
4. That's it, you should be able to refer the cookie's value as `${COOKIE_sessionid}` where required

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)